# UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?' s view global action method

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication

I have added a `button`, which I want to see top of all my `ViewControllers` with

`UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(mybutton)`

What I am trying to figure out is how can I make a global function that this `button` can call, no matter of which is my current `ViewController` ?

Answer (score 0):

Where you create your button add:

```
mybutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(mybutton)
```

Then in the same class add a method to handle whenever the button is pressed:

```
func buttonPressed() {
    // Button handling code here e.g:
    // StaticButtonHandler.handleButtonPress()
    // or 
    // ButtonHandler.sharedInstance.handleButtonPress()
}
```

If you need global code to be called from anywhere and it doesn't require state it would be easiest to put it in some static method:

```
class StaticButtonHandler {        
    static func handleButtonPress() {
        // Handle the button press
    }
}
```

Alternatively use the singleton pattern:

```
class ButtonHandler {
    static let sharedInstance = ButtonHandler()

    func handleButtonPress() {
        // Handle the button press
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that not I need. Please read the question. I am ofc aware that I can do that but it will work for the current ViewController that I am in. Again what I want is a global function that can be called from anywhere.

Comment: Added static method and singleton pattern to my answer to allow global code to be called from your button handler, or anywhere else, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a class in your code that will hold the "global" action method:

```
class GlobalActionHandler {
    @objc static func buttonClicked() {
        print("Button click handler")
    }
}
```

Then add a target and action to your button like this:

```
button.addTarget(GlobalActionHandler.self, 
                 action: #selector(GlobalActionHandler.buttonClicked), 
                 for: .touchUpInside)
```

You could also make `GlobalActionHandler` a singleton and `buttonClicked()` an instance method if you prefer.